# Maximize $\surd(K_1)+2\surd(L_1)+3\surd(K_2)+4\surd(L_2)$ with constraints $L=L_1+L_2, K=K_1+K_2$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics, extreme-value-analysis

From my computations, I have found

$$K_1^{*}=K/10, L_1^{*}=L/5, K_2^{*}=9K/10, L_2^{*}=4L/5, \lambda_1=\surd(5/2K), \lambda_2=\surd(5/L)$$

My Question is: How to find extreme value function $M(K, L)$.

First order conditions were

$L_{K_1}=1/(2\surd{K_1})-\lambda_1=0$

$L_{L_1}=1/\surd{L_1}-\lambda_2=0$

$L_{K_2}=3/(2\surd{K_2})-\lambda_1=0$

$L_{L_2}=2/\surd{L_2}-\lambda_2=0$

$L_{\lambda_1}=K-K_1-K_2=0$

$L_{\lambda_2}=L-L_1-L_2=0$

Do I have to use Hessian determinant approach but here are 4 variables, so how to tackle it?

Comment: If you want specific values for the variables you need specific values for K and L (parameters).

Comment: There is no specific values are being found. You can try if I am wrong.

Comment: Haven't you found optimal values, dependent on K and L? For instance, if $K=10$ then $K_1^*=1$ and $K_2^*=9$

Comment: But values for $K, L$ are not given I have to find extreme value function in $K, L$

Comment: Just insert the optimal values into the (objective) function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had done like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve the following problem:

\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{L_1,L_2,K_1,K_2} & \sqrt{K_1}+2\sqrt{L_1}+3\sqrt{K_2}+4\sqrt{L_2}\\ \text{s.t.} & K_1+K_2=K, \ L_1+L_2=L \\ \text{and } & K_1\geq 0, \ K_2\geq 0, \ L_1\geq 0, \ L_2\geq0\end{eqnarray*}

we can split this problem into two problems:

\begin{eqnarray}\max_{L_1,L_2} & \ 2\sqrt{L_1}+4\sqrt{L_2}\\ \text{s.t.} & L_1+L_2=L \\ \text{and } &  L_1\geq 0, \ L_2\geq0\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}\max_{K_1,K_2} & \ \sqrt{K_1}+3\sqrt{K_2}\\ \text{s.t.} &  K_1+K_2=K \\ \text{and } & K_1\geq 0, \ K_2\geq0\end{eqnarray}

Solutions to the above problems satisfy the following conditions:

\begin{eqnarray}\dfrac{\sqrt{L_2}}{2\sqrt{L_1}} & = & 1 \\ \dfrac{\sqrt{K_2}}{3\sqrt{K_1}} & = & 1 \\ L_1+L_2 & = & L \\ K_1 +K_2 & = & K\end{eqnarray}

Solving them we get,
\begin{eqnarray}L_1 = \dfrac{L}{5}, \ L_2 = \dfrac{4L}{5} \\ K_1 = \dfrac{K}{10}, \ K_2 = \dfrac{9K}{10}\end{eqnarray}

Optimal value of the objective is:
\begin{eqnarray} M(K,L)= \sqrt{10K}+\sqrt{20L} \end{eqnarray}